# How do you install Windows 8 with Bootcamp but without a SuperDrive?

Tags: windows-8, iso-image, boot-camp

I'm in an odd situation. I removed my superdrive in favour of a second hard drive and would now like to use bootcamp.

Does anyone have a process for installing Windows 8 with Bootcamp but without the DVD copy & reader?

(I already have the ISO)

Comment: Good question -- I had this issue before with the release preview and eventually gave up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to install [rEFIt](http://refit.sourceforge.net/) and use it to boot the MacBook to a bootable flash drive with the windows 8 installer.

Answer (score 0):

SLaks answer works. However, I also found a way to do without the flash drive:

http://huguesval.com/blog/2012/02/installing-windows-7-on-a-mac-without-superdrive-with-virtualbox/

It's **slightly** more complicated.